# Nginx map \x22password\x22 to hide POST logging

Tags: regex, nginx, logging

My logging is set up to log `$request_body` out to syslog, but it's including sensitive data in the logs.

For example, the password is coming through on the logs as `\x22password\x22` when the user logs in. For the time being, I want to persist the surrounding data and obfuscate the password only.

For example, when a user logs in and POSTs to the authentication backend, it's logged as

```
body: "{\x22username\x22:\x22myname@mydomain.com\x22,\x22password\x22:\x22One2Three4!?\x22}"
```

but I want it to be logged instead as

```
body: "{\x22username\x22:\x22myname@mydomain.com\x22,\x22password\x22:\x22********\x22}"
```

[I've seen there's an ability to map out fields in typical query string parameter formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772306/how-to-mask-sensitive-information-of-post-body-in-nginx-log), but I'm not particularly skilled at regex.

I've looked here [NGINX: Obfuscate password in access_log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396459/nginx-obfuscate-password-in-access-log) but the question isn't answered. Hoping to get some regex guidance on this one, regardless of best practices and security concerns.

How can I obfuscate the password in the logging with this format of response body?

Comment: Can you add to your question the part of your current nginx config related to logging?

Comment: Thanks. I added the question.

Comment: I wrote a couple of regex patterns for various cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396459/nginx-obfuscate-password-in-access-log/60119110#60119110), please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try some debugging first. Here are the regex that should work, but I'm not sure how it will behave if the password contains `\x22}` or `\x22,` substrings. Can you test it?

```
map $request_body $obfuscated_request_body {
    "~(.*[{,]\\x22password\\x22:\\x22).*?(\\x22[,}].*)" $1********$2;
    default $request_body;
}
```

Replace `$request_body` with `$obfuscated_request_body` in your `log_format` directive parameters. Note that the `map` block should be placed **outside** the `server` block.

**Update 1**

It seems that `\x22` substring will be shown as `\x5C\x5Cx22` in the log file, so regexp must be workable in any conditions.

Comment: With this map block in my appname.conf, I get the following errors: 
`2020/02/03 01:07:03 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected "{" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/appname.conf:5
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "{" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/appname.conf:5
`So I try to wrap the block in double quotes, but then I get:
`2020/02/03 01:24:03 [emerg] 1#1: invalid number of the map parameters in /etc/nginx/conf.d/appname.conf:6
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of the map parameters in /etc/nginx/conf.d/appname.conf:6`

Comment: @JonMitten Curly backets inside regex body are cause of this error, I'm updated my answer, try this one.

Comment: That worked great. Tested with curly braces as part of the password, and that gets obfuscated as well.

Comment: Can you test it with password that contains `\x22}` substring and with password that contains `\x22,` substring?

Comment: I've tested with `StupidPassword\x22` and I do indeed get `body: "{\x22username\x22:\x22myname@mydomain.com\x22,\x22password\x22:\x22********\x22}", upstream_status: "200"`. This looks good!

Comment: That is not exactly what I mean. Two passwords I want to be tested, for example, are `Stupid\x22}Password` and `Stupid\x22,Password`.

Comment: `Stupid\x22}Password` passes, is properly logged out as `********`. `Stupid\x22,Password` passes as well, and is properly logged as `********`. Thanks for following up with those test criteria.